# Запросы к серверу, события

Tags: java, android

Есть приложение, оно циклически отправляет запрос на сервер и если в ответ приходит новое сообщение то обновляет Лист вью. Скажите пожалуйста, это правильное решение или есть какой то более адекватный способ?

Comment: вместо long polling лучше использовать push сообщение, отправляемое сервером через FCM. получив его вы делаете 1 запрос на сервер и обновляете ваши данные. Не тратьте батарею пользователя на "обогрев воздуха"

Comment: Можете посоветовать статью по этому поводу?

Comment: Используя FCM, вы ставите себя и всю свою инфраструктуру от корпорации добра. Задумайтесь.

Comment: Ну как я понял, альтернатив не много